# How to fix an error when up uploading to apple store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am getting the error message below when I try to upload an app to the Apple store using Xcode.  The error message does not make sense to me because I am not using the assets catalog method of generating the launch screen (which is deprecated) but using the recommended approach of using a storyboard for the launch screen.

How do I fix this?

ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that on the Xcode project General tab, I had the Deployment target set to IOS 7.0, whereas it has to be on 8.0 or above. When I set it to 8.0, the error disappeared and the app successfully uploaded.

Comment: It does not have to be 8.0 or above. You can support iOS 7.0 if you need to. But then you would need to also use launch images for iOS 7.